# rtl radio input material kit

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having hard time to turn the radio button into RTL format. would you please help?

```html
<div class="form-check" style="width: 49%;text-align: right;position: inherit;display: inline-block;">
  <label class="form-check-label">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1"> فيلا
  <span class="circle">
    <span class="check"></span>
  </span>
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are circles... there's no left or right. If you want the `label` text to appear on the left, swap the order of the `<input type='radio">` and the `<label>` in the html. For any form field that includes text you can use `<input type='text' dir='rtl' />`

Answer (score 0):

just write the label container before the input container like this:

```html
<div class="form-check" style="width: 49%;text-align: right;position: inherit;display: inline-block;">
  <label class="form-check-label">فيلا</label>
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1"> 
  <span class="circle">
    <span class="check"></span>
  </span>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this situation `Html` layout change won't work anymore. It should be fixed using only `CSS` styles.

So apply below styles when you convert your html page arabic version.

```
.form-check {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

---

This style also works when `<html>` tag has `lang="ar".

```
<html lang="ar">
 <body>
  <div class="form-check" style="width: 49%;text-align: right;position: inherit;display: inline-block;">
   <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1"> فيلا
        <span class="circle">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </span>
    </label>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>



html[lang="ar"] .form-check {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

---

This code snippet shows live example.

```css
.form-check {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check" style="width: 49%;text-align: right;position: inherit;display: inline-block;">
  <label class="form-check-label">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1"> فيلا
  <span class="circle">
    <span class="check"></span>
  </span>
 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html[dir="rtl"] .form-check .form-check-label span{
    left: unset;
    right: -1px;
}
```

This style also works when  tag has `dir="rtl".

EX:

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
 ...
</html>
```